# Remove .com.example in android studio company domain by mistake

Tags: android, android-studio

I created an app using Android studio and when creating my project I stupidly put my company domain as .com.example.myname.myappname

Now that I am done my app, I cant upload the .apk to the play store.  I have tried refactoring but that just changes "myappname" and not the whole domain. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Do you see this topic?

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033790/in-android-studio-how-to-change-packages-file-path][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033790/in-android-studio-how-to-change-packages-file-path